# How to rename a file named "aggarwal1990" to "1990 Aggarwal", using R?

Tags: r

I have a lot of papers named like,

```
"aggarwal1990.pdf", "keim1984.pdf", "malkiel1970.pdf"
```

I want to make them like,

```
"1990 aggarwal.pdf", "1984 Keim.pdf", "1970 Malkie.pdf"
```

I figured this could be done by using regex, but I don't know how to do.

Suppose they are in my home directory like this "~/aggarwal1990.pdf".

Comment: Is it super necessary for there to be actual spaces in filenames? Even though it's 2018, spaces in filenames still usually cause more harm than good.

Comment: `file.rename(c("aggarwal1990.pdf", "keim1984.pdf", "malkiel1970.pdf"), c("1990 aggarwal.pdf", "1984 Keim.pdf", "1970 Malkie.pdf"))`

Comment: @hrbrmstr I am soooo fed up by this “wisdom”. I use spaces in filenames liberally. It works (outside of make, which, well. Let’s not talk about it).

Comment: glad it works for you. you are def one of a kind

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
sub('^(\\D+)(\\d{4})\\.pdf$', '\\2 \\1.pdf', filenames)
```